# Scrapy XPath - @href returning unexpected value

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I'm currently web-scraping restaurant reviews from Tripadvisor and I'm trying to retrieve restaurant links from this [page](https://www.tripadvisor.it/Restaurants-g187791-Rome_Lazio.html).

I want the links of the 30 restaurant pages in the bottom part but I'm making some tests with just one of them. Retrieving the first one in the list can be done with this expression:

```
//div[@data-test='1_list_item']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div//a/@href
```

Scrapy has some unexpected behaviours, the following css expression should be enough to retrieve all the links but instead, an empty array is returned:

```
response.css('.b::attr(href)').extract()
```

The same goes with many Xpath expression and by using the one above like this:

```
response.xpath("//div[@data-test='1_list_item']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div//a/@href").get()
```

I get the following link in return:

**/ShowUserReviews-g187791-d25107357-r916086825-ADESSO_Vineria_Bistrot-Rome_Lazio.html**

I don't know where this comes from, the link I can see in the inspect chrome console and that I expected to get in return is:

**/Restaurant_Review-g187791-d25107357-Reviews-ADESSO_Vineria_Bistrot-Rome_Lazio.html**

Comment: This should do it: `//div[contains(@data-test,'_list_item')]//div/div/div/span/a[starts-with(@href,'/Restaurant_Review')]/@href`

Comment: That's great, if you want you can leave this as an answer so I can accept it. Maybe leave some insights on the reasoning behind this expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using SIM's suggested xpath expression:

`//div[contains(@data-test,'_list_item')]//div/div/div/span/a[starts-with(@href,'/Restaurant_Review')]/@href`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are encountering when using Scrapy may be due to the fact that the TripAdvisor site loads the data feed using JavaScript, and Scrapy does not support JavaScript by default. As a result, when you try to fetch links using `response.css` or `response.xpath`, Scrapy only sees the initial state of the page without loading the loaded data.

To check the page that has been loaded, use the open_in_browser() function and read where the data you need is listed before writing the xpath or css selector.

Check it:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html

```
# import this util
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

# in spider class
... 
def parse_details(self, response):
    open_in_browser(response)
...
```

If you have problems using this example, then you can call `response.text` and check the current contents of the response page

Comment: Thank you, that's some very useful information. However I solved my problem using the expression suggested by SIM